# Find public IP with POCO

Tags: c++, network-programming, ip-address, poco-libraries

How can I find my public IP using POCO?

Inspired by page 6 of [their Network presentation](https://pocoproject.org/slides/200-Network.pdf), I tried the following:

```
#include "Poco/Net/DNS.h"
#include <iostream>
using Poco::Net::DNS;
using Poco::Net::HostEntry;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const HostEntry& entry = DNS::thisHost();
    std::cout << "Canonical Name: " << entry.name() << std::endl;

    const HostEntry::AliasList& aliases = entry.aliases();
    HostEntry::AliasList::const_iterator alias_it = aliases.begin();
    for (; alias_it != aliases.end(); ++alias_it)
        std::cout << "Alias: " << *alias_it << std::endl;

    const HostEntry::AddressList& addrs = entry.addresses();
    HostEntry::AddressList::const_iterator addr_it = addrs.begin();
    for (; addr_it != addrs.end(); ++addr_it)
        std::cout << "Address: " << addr_it->toString() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This, however, returned two addresses: one IPv6 link-local (fe80:...) and one private LAN IPv4 (10.0...). It did not return my public IP.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the host running the software using POCO is inside a local network using NAT, it is not directly possible to get the WAN-Address of the router (I guess you're meaning this when using the term "my public IP").

Instead, you have to use a public server's API returning your IP address, for example: https://www.ipify.org/